# Android layout : Align a TextView and a Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, alignment, spinner

I would like to align a textview (saying : "Day :") with a Spinner where the user can choose the day of the week he wants (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

when I try to align them :

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/labelSpinner1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/textSpinner1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_days"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_days"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/labelSpinner1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

the result I get is that I only see the Spinner, and the TextView isn't showing (or is underneath the Spinner)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9):

I guess you want the Spinner to the right of the TextView? Check the following code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelSpinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/textSpinner1" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_days"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/labelSpinner1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelSpinner1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Your problem was that the spinner filled the whole view (`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`) while you forced the TextView to be right of the Spinner (so outside of the screen --> invisible for you)

Comment: If I want to add a TextView aligned to a EditText, right on the bottom of the TextView and the Spinner, how should I do ?

Comment: That's somehow the same. Just reuse the code above and remove the alignParentTop-line and add to both new views (textview / edittext) `android:layout_below="@id/labelSpinner1"`.
Furthermore I recommend you to read the documentation for the different layout-types in android: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: does not apply to LinearLayout

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere True. Only `RelativeLayout` has the attribute `android:layout_toRightOf`. When you're using a `LinearLayout` you can easily achieve it by adding `android:orientation="horizontal"` (obviously you should wrap the `Spinner` and the `TextView` in a separate LinearLayout)

Comment: to solve it, what I ended up doing was keeping the LinearLayout (orientation = horizontal) and in the spinner I set the layoutGravity to "bottom". Now spinner and TextInputEditText (inside TextInputLayout) are really well aligned.